# mssql сортировка

Tags: sql-server

в бд есть такой набор данных, например:

```
А5-23-0,25
С8-22-0,18
ОМЛТ-1-В-5,1
M5x13
M8х5
1206-20
2ГДШ-16 4
2М2-6H.04.013
C2-23-1-1,2
К10-47А-100В-0,22
К10-47А-100В-0,23.
```

что прописывать в order by, чтобы данные сортировались таким образом (т.е. сортировка была натуральной (5<12), если числа и по алфавиту):

```
1206-20
2ГДШ-16 4
2М2-6H.04.013
А5-23-0,25
К10-47А-100В-0,22
К10-47А-100В-0,25
М5х8
M5x13
M8х5
ОМЛТ-1-В-5,1
C2-23-1-1,2
C2-23-1-11
С8-22-0,18?
```

всего подобных данных в бд около 11000.

Comment: А почему 1206 тут оказывается меньше, чем 2?

Comment: В текущей постановке задачи данные - нереляционны. И требовать их обработку реляционно без предварительной нормализации - несерьёзно.